# Writing data to a zip file

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I have a script which I am running in the ubuntu terminal (bash) . Currently I am directly appending the output of the script to a file using the below command :

./run.sh > a.txt

But for some input files run.sh may produce output which is large in size without compression . Is it possible to write these output directly to a zip file without going through the dump file intermediate ? 
I know it is possible in Java and python . But I wanted a general method of doing it in the bash so that I could keep the run.sh same even if my running program is changing .

I have tried searching the web but haven't come across something useful .

Comment: Have you tried `./run.sh | zip > file.zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a gzip file would be more appropriate. Unlike zip, which is an archive format, gzip is just a compressed data format and can easily be used in a pipe:

```
./run.sh | gzip > a.txt.gz
```

The resulting file can be uncompressed in place using the `gunzip` command (resulting in a file `a.txt`), viewed with `zmore` or listed with `zcat` which allows you to process the output with a filter without writing the whole decompressed file anywhere.

Comment: To be clear , Say the output of ./run.sh is around 10 Gb and I have a space of around 8 Gb left on my disk . Doing the above would directly produce the compress zip file (say it's size if less than 8 Gb) without ever producing the intermediate output .

Comment: Correct. No intermediate files are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The 'zip' format is for archiving. The 'zip' program can take an existing file and put compressed version into an archive. For example:

```
./run.sh > a.txt
zip a.zip a.txt
```

However, you question ask specifically for a 'streaming' solution (given file size). There are few utilities that use formats that are 'streaming-happy': gz, bz2, and xz. Each excel in different type of data, but for many cases, all will work.

```
./run.sh | gzip > a.txt.gz
./run.sh | bzip2 > a.txt.bz2
./run.sh | xz > a.txt.xz
```

If you are looking for widest compatibility, gzip is usually your friend.

Comment: +1 for mentioning alternative stream compression options. You might want to edit the first example so that the line break between the two commands is visible.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can use process substitution.

```
zip -FI -r file.zip <(./run.sh)
```

Comment: Zip usually works with files, On Mint19: 'zip warning: ignoring FIFO (Named Pipe) - use -FI to read: /dev/fd/63'. Even with '-FI' extracting the data becomes a challenge